# Stuck in low-graphics mode, normal method not working

Tags: updates, graphics, lightdm, tty

I just got a notification to take the Ubuntu 14.04 update. What could go wrong, right? I'm stuck in low-graphics mode. It's similar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error/218095?noredirect=1#comment700712_218095). The problem is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't take me to a terminal. It takes me to a screen that says:

```
Initializing built-in extension XXXX
Loading extension GLS
Loading extension
etc
etc
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could guess that the `TTY1` is showing that information but the rest of the TTY (2 to 6) do not). So my advice is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> and see if you get the login prompt there. If you do, then follow on with the rest of the steps.

Comment: ctrl+alt+2 or 3 don't seem to work either. I can get to the terminal if I don't go into recovery mode by pressing ctrl+alt+f4.  Is it possible to somehow fix the issue from there, or from the root shell in recovery mode?

Comment: You can fix it from there or recovery. I am glad that at least F4 works. I would do a full upgrade from there, many times an update will fix this.

Comment: So basically you suggest running these commands? http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/it-help-center/how-to/upgrading-ubuntu-via-command-line

Comment: @schwiz correct. I even would go out and suggest to do a "reinstall" of the packages just in case one of them does not install but still is missing a configuration file. That would be like "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg"

Comment: So I tried the reinstall like you said but it fails saying no space left on device tons of times. I have 11 gigs of free space.  Although, if I run df on the /tmp folder its trying to use it says the size is only 1M

Comment: Any news about this case?

Comment: Crazy thing, I woke up one morning and it was fixed. I think my issue was I ran out of disc space. Once I deleted stuff it somehow fixed itself while I was away.